# How to allow IPIP (IP encap, proto 4) with ufw?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ufw

I have tried:

```
# ufw allow proto ip-encap from 198.51.100.3
ERROR: Unsupported protocol 'ip-encap'
# ufw allow proto ipip from 198.51.100.3
ERROR: Unsupported protocol 'ipip'
# ufw allow proto 4 from 198.51.100.3
ERROR: Unsupported protocol '4'
#
```

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing. Edit /etc/ufw/before.rules just  before COMMIT

-A ufw-before-input -p 4 -j ACCEPT

Comment: sorry that is /etc/ufw/before.rules

Comment: The frustrating thing is, it seems packets are accepted, even without adding the rule (but ufw enabled). Can you confirm this?